# Difference between みたいに and みたいな in this sentence

Tags: nuances

この写真みたいなヘアースタイルにしてください。

Why in this sentence I cant't use みたいに instead of みたいな?
And how this sentence should be changed to make usage of みたいに relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「この写真{しゃしん}みたい**な**ヘアースタイルにしてください。」

In this sentence, 「この写真みたい**な**」 is an **adjectival** phrase that modifies the noun 「ヘアースタイル」.

「みたい**に**」 with a 「に」 is an **adveribial** phrase; therefore, it cannot modify a noun.

To use 「みたい**に**」 correctly in that sentence, you would need to change the sentence structure so that 「～～みたい**に**」 can correctly modify the verb phrase 「してください」.  To do that, you could say:

> 「ヘアースタイル**を**、この写真みたい**に**してください。」